# how to call function when slider stops in angular-rangeslider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using slider https://github.com/danielcrisp/angular-rangeslider

my question is that how to call controller function when slider stops for example

```
<div range-slider min="0" max="100" model-min="min" model-max="max"></div>
```

so how to bind event in this slider when slider stops ?

i find something like this

```
scopeOptions = {
                    disabled: '=?',
                    min: '=',
                    max: '=',
                    modelMin: '=?',
                    modelMax: '=?',
                    onHandleDown: '&', // calls optional function when handle is grabbed
                    onHandleUp: '&', // calls optional function when handle is released
                    orientation: '@', // options: horizontal | vertical | vertical left | vertical right
                    step: '@',
                    decimalPlaces: '@',
                    filter: '@',
                    filterOptions: '@',
                    showValues: '@',
                    pinHandle: '@',
                    preventEqualMinMax: '@',
                    attachHandleValues: '@'
                };
```

Comment: I would suggest you to add a model tag to the rangeslider and then listen to the change in that particular model using $watchCollection or $watch. You can put your login inside the callback of $watch or $watchCollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the options as your question, and there you can find something called `onHandleUp` and it's described as `calls optional function when handle is released`. so if you pass a function to this option then that function will call when slider stops.

for ex:

add `on-handle-up` option,

```
<div range-slider min="0" max="100" model-min="demo1.min" model-max="demo1.max" on-handle-up="sliderStops()"></div>
```

create the `sliderStops()` function in controller,

```
 $scope.sliderStops = function() {
  alert("slider stops.");
}
```

here is the **[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6WGfy2TFpqmJnpo1N7q2?p=preview)**

If you need to call a function when slider starts use `onHandleDown` option, as same as `onHandleUp`.

```
<div range-slider min="0" max="100" model-min="demo1.min" model-max="demo1.max" on-handle-up="sliderStops()" on-handle-down="sliderStats()"></div>

$scope.sliderStats = function() {
    console.log("slider starts.");
}
```

here is the **[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GHAPGUXg6l6FuGYXW9DH?p=preview)**. Open the console and slide and check the console outputs.

Comment: you beat me by 1 min :-P I am not posting my answer :-) Bingo +1

Comment: @OP there are two events provided by module you used onHandleUp and  onHandleDown. The first one is called after ranger stopped and the second one is called when ranger just start sliding.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion and i update the answer with `on-handle-down` :)